# Use of Operator ->*

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overload the ->* operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587152/how-to-overload-the-operator)

What is the meaning of operator `->*`?

and how it can be useful in overloading ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696864/are-free-operator-overloads-evil . I don't think this is a duplicate of the above, but not a really good question either.

Comment: I was going to answer, but here is the jist — `operator->*` defines a binary operator just like `operator+`, `operator*`, etc. It has higher precedence than all the other binary operators so it is useful in forming member accesses, but lower than `operator[]`. It is widely considered to be obscure and may confuse users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->*` and `.*` operators are for accessing class members via pointers, see the following link for examples:

http://c-for-crogrammers.org.ua/ch22lev1sec6.html

You may find [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1705603/505154) useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

`operator->*` is for pointers to members.

```
struct foo{
  void bar(){}
};

int main(){
  typedef void (foo:*foo_memptr)();
  foo_memptr pfunc = &foo::bar;
  foo f;
  foo* pf = &f;
  (f.*pfunc)(); // on object or reference
  (pf->*pfunc)(); // on pointer to object
}
```

Overloading it is usually *only* useful for smart pointers, and even them don't do it because it's really complicated and the same functionality can be achieved by `((*pf).*pfunc)()`. Scott Meyers even wrote [a PDF on how to do it](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf)!